# EditText with TextWatcher shows wired behaviour and move in recursive loop

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, barcode-scanner, textwatcher

I am getting data from barcode scanning into an edittext. On that Edittext i have applied the addTextChangedListener with Textwatcher class. But it is showing a wired behaviour. It's working fine on 1st time but from next time it's moving into a recursive loop. The one item i have scan added three times due the recursive behaviour of this Edittext. Below is the code i am using.

```
 EditText   barcodeScanner =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.barcodeFocus);
    TextWatcher  textwatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.d("@@@@", s.toString());
                if (s.length() > 1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    if(flag){
                        char lastCharacter = s.charAt(s.length() - 1); 

                        if (lastCharacter == 'p') { 
                            String barcode = s.subSequence(0, s.length() - 1).toString();
                            Log.d("Id before parsing", barcode);
                            int btnId = Integer.parseInt(barcode.trim());

                                getItemsInformation(btnId);

                        } 
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    else
                        flag = true;
                }
            }

        };
        barcodeScanner.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher); 

private void getItemsInformation(int btnId) {
        ProductOptionsDbHandler productOptionDbHandler = new ProductOptionsDbHandler(this);
        List<String> optionNames = productOptionDbHandler.getProductOptions(btnId);
        Product productdetails = prodDbHand.getSelecteProductsDetails(btnId);
        float price =   productdetails.getProductPrice();
        if(optionNames.size()>0 || price == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ItemPopUpTabActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("intVariableName", btnId);
            intent.putExtra("itemPrice", price);
            intent.putExtra("itemTax", productdetails.getTaxRate());
            startActivity(intent);
            barcodeScanner.removeTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
            barcodeScanner.setText("");
            barcodeScanner.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
        }
        else{
            listofItemList.add(productdetails);
            QtyOfItems.add(1);
            ItemsPrice.add(price);
            ItemsIds.add(productdetails.getProductId());
            itemTaxRate.add(productdetails.getTaxRate());
            addItemintocheckoutList(price,productdetails);
            List<String> itemsOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
            itemsOptionsIds.add(itemsOptions);
            Variables.itemposition++;
            barcodeScanner.removeTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
            barcodeScanner.setText("");
            barcodeScanner.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
        }

    }
```

The input for the barcode is like 002p. I have tried with

```
barcodeScanner.removeTextChangedListener(textwatcher);

barcodeScanner.setText("");

barcodeScanner.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
```

after doing the job in the end but nothing changed. I already tried the one similer issue raised by someone on SO [EditText, OnKeyListener or TextWatcher (barcode scanning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151499/edittext-onkeylistener-or-textwatcher-barcode-scanning)
Please guide me where i am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [check this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20416174/624069)

Comment: @CapDroid why it's moving into recursive loop ?

Comment: The problem is with  if (s.length() > 0) line it will always be true . You have to change your algo whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

YOur problem is that it counts each character you enters separately so if you enter a single digit input it works well otherwise it takes each character of an input . I have the same problem and still haven't solved it